# Sap Commerce (hybris): Search page doesn't show products

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

after a content catalog sync the search page doesn't show products.

Solr works fine: it return the list of products and the total numenr of retrieved product is showed on the page but not the products.

[image: Search page]

Paginator looks fine and also the search box works correctly (it found the products and show images of them on the list below the search box).

[image: search box]

where is the issue?

my expetations is the list of products.

Solr indexing doesn't help.

Comment: Have you checked if the JSON response for the /search API returns any products? If yes, then there may be something wrong with your CMS or frontend. Also, is there anything in the browser console logs or network errors?

Comment: no logs availble. Pretty sure that the cause is something wrong on CMS (we ran some impex for add a new addon). I will check JSON

Comment: After an initialize (on my machine) all works fine

Answer (score 1):

Just before the sync we ran some impex of content catalog.
One of the impex was related to Search page with the activation/deactivation of grid and list product search pages.

From backoffice we switched the activation, re-sync and now all is working.